# Does laravel 9 accepts putting models inside a subfolder ? Like App\Models\Users\User.php

Tags: laravel, model, subdirectory

Right after a new laravel 9 installation, ran the code `php artisan make:model Users/User -m` (and some others in the same path).

Also created a controller AuthController, with 2 methods (register and login)

Register works fine, saves to DB correctly with no problem (using POSTMAN)

But when I try to login, this error appears >

```
{
    "message": "Class \"\\App\\Models\\User\" not found",
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "D:\\sdk\\UniServerZ\\www\\ipas\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php",
    "line": 183,
```

As error says, it's looking for App\Models\User file, which not exist, because when I created the model y said that I wanted to be inside USERS folder ( App\Models\Users\User ) is the correct path.

So, anyone know how can i achieve this ? all my models files were put inside a subfolder, not in Models folder directly D:

Also... I've used namespaces >
in AuthController `use App\Models\Users\User;`

in User model> `namespace App\Models\Users;`

Hope you guys understand what I mean, because of my bad english :S

btw, I'm using Sanctum...

I've traced the code, and realized the exception occurs inside login method, in Auth::attempt line > (I've done a print_r, and works)

```
    public function login(Request $request){
        if( !Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password')) ){
            return response()
            ->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized']);
        }

        $user   = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

        $token  = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'user'          => $user->name,
            'token'         => $token,
            'token_type'    => 'Bearer',
            'user'          => $user
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: the Auth system would need to know what Model to use for authentication (by default the `web` guard uses the `users` provider which uses `App\Models\User`) ... make the adjustment in your `config/auth.php` file under `providers -> users`

Comment: **thanks a lot** @lagbox !! that solved my problem!

`'model' => App\Models\Users\User::class,`